# Trouble on creating a JSON Object on Android

Tags: android, json

I'm having a provblem on creating a JSON object on android app.

I's getting a JSON array like :

```
[{"estado":"1","longitude":"19.1714172","latitude":"-8.9477729"},{"estado":"1","longitude":"37.1714681","latitude":"-8.9476652"}]
```

from the server (using a servlet).

But when i try to access the array objects on a for cicle like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //the rest of code
            }
```

my app gives some error, and simple stop (something like an ANR! i'm not sure about this).

Can anyone help? please.

Comment: check ur logcat for error......

Comment: the json array is not named?

Comment: Sorry guys, was my bad put the "!" on the end of sentences! I remove my comments! Hope u can forgive-me! :). @reidzeibel give the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please remove the exclamation mark "!" at the end of your sentences, it might offend somebody here ^^

Okay, onto your problem, I suggest to encapsulate your JSON array inside a json object, maybe like this :

```
{"data":[{"estado":"1","longitude":"19.1714172","latitude":"-8.9477729"},{"estado":"1","longitude":"37.1714681","latitude":"-8.9476652"}]}
```

For example, we save that result string inside a `String` called `jsontext`, then we would create a `JSONObject` from that string, grab the `JSONArray`, and parse the `JSONObject` on the array. Here's a little snippet :

```
String jsontext = "yourjsontext"; 
//if it's from a http response, you might call respon

JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject("jsontext");
JSONArray jsonArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //the rest of code
} code here
```

Hope this helps, good luck ^^

Regards,

Reid

Comment: First of all, THANKS FOR UR REPREENTION. Was not my intention offend somebady, is just a simple bad habit put the "!" at the end of my senteces. I do what u suggest and it works great! Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome and thanks for your response too, glad I could help, good luck on your app ^^